# Camera in Flash air

Tags: android, ios, flash, air, camera

How to get 2 camera active at the same time?

My code:

```
var cam1:Camera = Camera.getCamera("0");
var cam2:Camera = Camera.getCamera("1");


var vid1:Video = new Video();
vid1.attachCamera(cam1);
mydiv1.addChild(vid1);

var vid2:Video = new Video();
vid2.attachCamera(cam2);
mydiv2.addChild(vid2);
```

With this there is only 1 of 2 cameras active. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28int%29) : you can have one Camera Active at the same time

Comment: How? I do not. Help me pls

Comment: You should clarify the one camera at a time is a restriction on mobile devices. You can use multiple cameras at the same time in a web based Flash app.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge upto now we can enable only one camera at a time .

Comment: when the new are supported?

Comment: But i need on flash air

Answer (score 0):

AIR has to play by the rules set forth by the systems it runs on. So if Android or iOS or Windows or Mac do not support something, neither does AIR. There is no support for multiple cameras on Android and I do not believe there is on iOS either. There is no way around this, there is nothing you can do.